# Texlive installation issue: repository database loading takes forever

Tags: texlive, installing

I am trying to install Texlive 2014 on my Windows 7 laptop.
The issue is that when I run "install-tl-windows" in the command line, and I press next in the GUI that pops up, I get a message saying "Please wait while the repository database is loaded. This will take some time!"
I was expecting it to take **some** time, but after 12 hours of waiting (I was doing other stuff for sure :P), I concluded that nothing is happening and that I am waiting for nothing!
Any idea what the issue could be, or at least how to check if any progress is actually happening?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Have you got some messages? Have you checked if there are messages in the system protocol of windows?

Comment: I got no visible messages, it was just stuck there with no further visible progress
What is the "system protocol" exactly? and how do I check if there is any messages there?

Comment: Hi,
I managed to find what you're pointing to, and btw the exact translations are as follows:
Systemsteuerung: Control Panel, System und Sicherheit: System and Security, Verwaltung: Administrative tools, Ereignisprotokolle anzeigen: View event logs.

However, I failed to find anything clearly saying Texlive (or TL) :(

Comment: mmmm, thanks anyway... I hope that someone can help soon since I have a report to work on :(

Comment: **bold** `News:` After asking someone, I tried to rerun the installation using the verbose argument -vv, and I got the following error message:
Tk::Error: Aborting, cannot find either scheme-full or scheme_minimal at C:\texlive\2014\install-tl line 1444
I have no idea what scheme-full and scheme_minimal are... I hope someone can help

Answer (score 1):

From your question I understand you are trying to install over the internet. Due to automatic mirror selection, this process may not be the most efficient one. Try installing from ISO. The image can be downloaded [here.](http://ftp.snt.utwente.nl/pub/software/tex/systems/texlive/Images/)

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem. Choosing the 'unpack only' option, and then running the batch file (like the installer suggests) from the location where the unpacked stuff is located worked for me.

Comment: I don't believe you. It is not possible to install TL 2014 any longer unless you kept a private copy of the repository.